# undefined method generated by controller action when apparently defined in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

The class has the following methods defined in the model:

```
def EWKB
  RGeo::WKRep::WKBGenerator.new(:type_format => :ewkb, :emit_ewkb_srid => true, :hex_format => true)
end

def self.containing_latlon(lat, lon, polygon)
  ewkb = EWKB.generate(FACTORY.point(lon, lat).projection)
  where("ST_Intersects(polygon, ST_GeomFromEWKB(E'\\\\x#{ewkb}'))")
end
```

When calling an action in the class controller as such

```
point_in = containing_latlon(@point_p.lat, @point_p.lon, @polygon)
```

Rails returns a NoMethodError

```
undefined method `containing_latlon'
```

I fail to understand why this method is deemed undefined

**Edit**
garry's comment below is correct.

Comment: change controller to `point_in = ModalName.containing_latlon(@point_p.lat, @point_p.lon, @polygon)`

Comment: was playing whack-a-mole there with three issues and never sorting it out!

Answer (score 0):

It's a class method, as you define inside your code

```
self.containing_latlon(lat, lon, polygon)
```

You have to call it with class name (Model Name).

```
ModalName.containing_latlon(lat, lon, polygon)
```

lat, lon, polygon are variable which you are sending to containing_latlon method